# Fixing date data scraped from wikipedia with R

Tags: r

I'm scraping data from wikipedia using R ([working example](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=FasBJQbK&version=3)):

```
library(reshape)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
theurl <- getURL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_42nd_Canadian_federal_election", ssl.verifyPeer=FALSE)
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
raw_polling_data <- tables[[2]]
```

But date data comes in as funky format with all these preceding 0's:

```
           Polling Firm      Last Date\nof Polling                Link Cons.
1        Nanos Research      000000002015-07-31-0000July 31, 2015  PDF  31.5
2   Innovative Research      000000002015-07-30-0000July 30, 2015 HTML  29.3
3        Forum Research      000000002015-07-28-0000July 28, 2015  PDF    33
4                  EKOS      000000002015-07-28-0000July 28, 2015  PDF  30.1
5            Ipsos Reid      000000002015-07-27-0000July 27, 2015 HTML    33
6   Mainstreet Research      000000002015-07-21-0000July 21, 2015 HTML    38
7        Forum Research      000000002015-07-20-0000July 20, 2015  PDF    28
...
```

How can I turn those dates into just yyyy-mm-dd, within the table, to get this:

```
           Polling Firm      Date...    Link Cons.
1        Nanos Research      2015-07-31  PDF  31.5
2   Innovative Research      2015-07-30 HTML  29.3
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the number of leading 0 is always the same (i.e. 8)

```
cleanDate <- as.Date(substr(raw_polling_data[, 2], 9, 18))
```

To check

```
head(cleanDate)
[1] "2015-07-31" "2015-07-30" "2015-07-28" "2015-07-28" "2015-07-27" "2015-07-21"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you do this without taking it out of the table? Or putting it back in after?

Comment: Looks like I can just do this:
`raw_polling_data$'Last Date\nof Polling' = as.Date(substr(raw_polling_data[, 2], 9, 18))`
To edit the table column directly by addressing it by its name

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding problem. Try [htmltab](http://www.r-datacollection.com/blog/htmltab-v0.6.0/). For the moment, use the github version:

```
devtools::install_github("crubba/htmltab")
library("htmltab")
htmltab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_42nd_Canadian_federal_election", which = 2)
```

Comment: When I try this I get:
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Polling Firm", "Last Date of Polling",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
Header dimension doesn't match body dimension

Comment: Do you use the github version?